# XSL increment template parameter

Tags: xslt

Input:

```
    <root>
    <trip>
        <ID>3295</ID>        
        <ordini>
            <NR>821321</NR>
            <!-- some info -->
        </ordini>
        <ordini>
             <NR>234</NR>
            <!-- some info -->
        </ordini>
</trip>
<trip>
        <ID>23</ID>      
        <ordini>
         <NR>2321</NR>
            <!-- some info -->
        </ordini>
        <ordini>
           <NR>999</NR>
            <!-- some info -->
        </ordini>
        <ordini>
         <NR>232132131</NR>
            <!-- some info -->
        </ordini>
    </trip>
    </root>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" /> 
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>   
    <xsl:template name="set-row">      
        <xsl:param name="runningtot"/>
        <xsl:param name="node"/>       
             <xsl:value-of select="$runningtot + 1"/> 
             <xsl:if test="$node/following-sibling::ordini">
             <xsl:call-template name="set-row">            
                <xsl:with-param name="runningtot" select="$runningtot + 1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="node" select="$node/following-sibling::ordini[1]"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ordini">
    <xsl:for-each select="//ordini">
        <ordini>
            <NR> 
                 <xsl:call-template name="set-row">               
                <xsl:with-param name="runningtot" select="0"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="node" select="ordini"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            </NR>           
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ordini>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Desired output:

```
<root>
<trip>
        <ID>3295</ID>        
        <ordini>
        <NR>1</NR>
            <!-- some info -->
        </ordini>
        <ordini>
        <NR>2</NR>
            <!-- some info -->
        </ordini> 
</trip>
<trip>
        <ID>23</ID>      
        <ordini>
        <NR>1</NR>
            <!-- some info -->
        </ordini>
        <ordini>
        <NR>2</NR>
            <!-- some info -->
        </ordini>
        <ordini>
        <NR>3</NR>
            <!-- some info -->
        </ordini> 
</trip>
</root>
```

Basically, I want for each 'ordini' tag to REPLACE the 'NR' tag, where I count, starting from 1 and incrementing, each 'ordini' tag in the parent 'trip' tag.
Saw this template with parameter answer on here, that is used for recurring increment counts, but I can't make it work for me.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a template matching `ordini` but then you go and select all `ordini` elements in the document (as that is what `//ordini`) selects.

There is a much simpler solution in this case anyway, rather than using that `set-row` template. Simply use `xsl:number`

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" /> 

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>   

    <xsl:template match="ordini">
        <ordini>
            <NR> 
                 <xsl:number />
            </NR>           
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ordini>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```